# AWS IAM - How to disable users from making changes via the console, but allow API changes via CLI

Tags: amazon-iam

For Amazon Webservices IAM, is there a way where I can create a role with some policies that only allow Read in the Console, yet allows Read/Write using the API/CLI/Terraform.

The purpose is to force usage of infrastructure-as-code to avoid configuration drift.

Any insights or references to Best practices are very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's important to be clear that there is no fool-proof way to do this. No system can ever be sure how a request was made on the client side.

That being said, there should be a way to achieve what you are looking for. You will want to use the IAM condition `aws:UserAgent` (docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html)) to prevent users from using the browser. Here is an example:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "*",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": "*",
      "Resource": "*"
      "Condition": {
          "StringLike": {
              "aws:UserAgent": "console.amazonaws.com"
          }
       }
    }
  ]
}
```

CloudTrail logs the UserAgents for requests, so you could use that to figure out which UserAgents to block. (docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-event-reference-record-contents.html))